# Akka Streams: How to construct a Source of Sources with GraphDSL?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, alpakka

Here's a simple scenario.

Let's begin with a single Akka Source: let's say, of rows retrieved from a database. Based on a partitioning function, different rows need to be diverted into different streams. So, we use a fan-out operator, for which we need to use GraphDSL (can't just use just simple functions such as `.via` and `.to` for this).

So, in the builder block of `GraphDSL.create() { builder => [block]}`, we create a Partition of the `UniformFanOutShape` and connect the original Source's outlet with the Partition's inlet. The Partition's outlets, for the time being, are hanging out in the breeze.

Next, we should format the rows in each separate stream as CSV. Alpakka has a CSV module, and we can use the `akka.stream.alpakka.csv.scaladsl.CsvFormatting.format([arguments])` Flow for that purpose. So, we `.add` some CSV-formatting Flows to the builder (one per each fanned-out stream), and connect each Partition's outlet to its corresponding Flow's inlet. The Flows' outlets are hanging out in the breeze.

Next, we should attach filenames to each CSV-formatted stream and zip them together. Alpakka has an Archive module, which can zip from multiple Sources. The problem is that `akka.stream.alpakka.file.scaladsl.Archive.zip()` returns a `Flow[(ArchiveMetadata, Source[ByteString, Any]), ByteString, NotUsed]`. It's a Flow of Sources (let's ignore the `AchiveMetadata` part, which corresponds to the filenames), for which we need a Source of Sources to pipe data from--or at least, a collection of Sources (which we can pass to `Source.apply`).

The graph we have been building so far has a collection of outlets hanging in the breeze. But we can only produce a single graph from that builder block, right? We can wrap it up as a Graph of `AmorphousShape` with no inlets and N outlets. The question is how to transform it into a collection of Sources, one per each CSV-formatting outlet described above.

Or is there another way entirely? Please suggest.

P.S. Looking at the Akka source code, we have:

```
  /**
   * Creates a new [[Graph]] by passing a [[GraphDSL.Builder]] to the given create function.
   */
  def create[S <: Shape]()(buildBlock: GraphDSL.Builder[NotUsed] => S): Graph[S, NotUsed] = {
    val builder = new GraphDSL.Builder
    val s = buildBlock(builder)

    createGraph(s, builder)
  }
```

What I'd love to have is something like this:

```
  def createMultiple[S <: Shape]()(buildBlock: GraphDSL.Builder[NotUsed] => Seq[S]): Graph[S, NotUsed] = {
    val builder = new GraphDSL.Builder
    val shapes = buildBlock(builder)

    shapes.map(createGraph(_, builder))
  }
```

Unfortunately, `new GraphDSL.Builder` is private to the package. The `createGraph` that takes a Shape is private, too. Oops.

The other problem with that is: if we do bypass the private keyword, and if there is more than one fanning-out stream (everything works fine with only one), then for each `SourceShape` in the constructed collection, not all Partition outlets appear to be connected (because the others are connected through the other sources), resulting in an error. I suspect traversals are the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could attach [`Sink.asPublisher`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Sink/asPublisher.html)s to the loose outlets in the graph: each `Sink.publisher` will materialize as a Reactive Streams publisher (which is the Reactive Streams equivalent to an Akka `Source`).  Those publishers can then be converted into `Source`s using `Source.fromPublisher`.

Using [the `GraphDSL.create` overload which takes a sequence of graphs to inject](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.9.1/akka/stream/scaladsl/GraphDSL$.html#create%5BS%3C:akka.stream.Shape,IS%3C:akka.stream.Shape,Mat%5D(graphs:Seq%5Bakka.stream.Graph%5BIS,Mat%5D%5D)(buildBlock:akka.stream.scaladsl.GraphDSL.Builder%5BSeq%5BMat%5D%5D=%3E(Seq%5BIS%5D=%3ES)):akka.stream.Graph%5BS,Seq%5BMat%5D%5D) would materialize as a sequence of the materialized values of the injected graphs.  Since every outlet of this graph is capped by a sink, it itself has a `SinkShape`.  Attach your source to that sink and `run()` it to get a sequence of publishers.  From there it's just a matter of `Source(publishers).map(Source.fromPublisher).via(Archive.zip())`.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks! But how exactly do I drag those publishers out of the GraphDSL's building block? I don't want the original Source to be executed many times, and the Builder deep-copies the elements. So, I can only use one Builder. But when I tried slicing its Traversal into parts corresponding to each Sink, that didn't work.

Comment: Also, I don't know a priori how many sinks there would be. It depends. So, I need a collection of graphs as an argument, not the overloads with different number of graphs.

Comment: There's an overload which takes a `Seq` of (in this case) sinks.  The publishers will end up as the materialized value of the graph.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see it now. That would work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Levi. I have actually done something similar, taking the outlets out of the graph--although not as Publishers.

A disclosure: The service I'm working on is actually written in Clojure. So, I call Scala from Clojure, essentially writing Scala code with Clojure syntax. (All implicits have to be spelled out, of course. But hey, the Clojure compiler happily ignores the way Scala handles the `private` keyword. Can be useful at times.)

What I did was use `GraphStage` to create custom Sources and Sinks for Clojure channels. With those Sinks, the graph described in my original question has the `ClosedShape`. Using those custom Sources, I construct a simpler graph to funnel everything through `Archive.zip` (or, rather, `(Archive/zip)` in Clojure). The `clojure.core.async` channels serve as wormholes between the two otherwise disconnected universes (ahem, Akka graphs).

```
(defn channel->source [channel name]
  (let [outlet  (Outlet/apply name)
        shape   (SourceShape/apply outlet)
        logic   (proxy [GraphStageLogic] [shape])
        handler (reify OutHandler
                  (onPull [_]
                    (->> channel
                         async/<!!
                         (.push logic outlet))))
        graph   (proxy [GraphStage] []
                  (shape [] shape)
                  (createLogic [_]
                    (.setHandler logic outlet handler)
                    logic))]
    (Source/fromGraph graph)))

(defn channel->sink [channel name]
  (let [inlet   (Inlet/apply name)
        shape   (SinkShape/apply inlet)
        logic   (proxy [GraphStageLogic] [shape]
                  (preStart [] (.pull this inlet)))
        handler (reify InHandler
                  (onPush [_]
                    (->> inlet
                         (.grab logic)
                         (async/>!! channel))
                    (.pull logic inlet)))
        graph   (proxy [GraphStage] []
                  (shape [] shape)
                  (createLogic [_]
                    (.setHandler logic inlet handler)
                    logic))]
    (Sink/fromGraph graph)))
```

There is, of course, the question of how those Clojure wormholes would handle backpressure. But when out of buffer, the Clojure channels will block the Sinks, which should backpressure everything upstream. Not that I expect either JDBC or ElasticSearch calls to a remote data repo be any faster than zipping in memory.

Comment: Coincidentally, Scala is my #1 favorite language, but Clojure is #2. :)